# Undefined method 'execute' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am attempting to write the following code for Capistrano 3 on a rails app that I am working on. The error I receive is the message that is pasted on the title of the post.

```
196  namespace :swconfig do
197   desc "Install Bazaar xmllog plugin."
198   task :install_bzr_xmllog do
199     puts "Installing Bazaar xmllog..."
200     execute "rm -rf /home/deployer/.bazaar/plugins/xmloutput"
201     execute "mkdir -p /home/deployer/.bazaar/plugins && cd /home/deployer/.bazaar    /plugins && bzr branch lp:~amujumdar/bzr-xmloutput/emit_authors xmloutput"
202   end
203
204   desc "Upgrade rack"
205   task :upgrade_rack do
206     puts "Upgrading rack to 1.5.2"
207     execute "gem install rack -v1.5.2"
208   end
209
210 end
```

I've read a plentiful amount of research regarding upgrading Capistrano from 2, Capistrano in general from its official website, and stack overflow, but I am not sure what the problem is.

Because the syntax was from Capistrano 2, the 'execute' key word was previously labeled 'run'which of course gave me the error Undefined method 'run' for main:Object. However, substituting run into execute did not fix the error. I've also tried this variation of the execute syntax.

```
196  namespace :swconfig do
197   desc "Install Bazaar xmllog plugin."
198   task :install_bzr_xmllog do
199     puts "Installing Bazaar xmllog..."
200     execute :rm, " -rf /home/deployer/.bazaar/plugins/xmloutput"
```

This still produces the same error. According to Capistrano's official website [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/) the correct syntax should be the variation immediately above. However, in this article that I found, [Writing Capistrano Tasks](http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/04/10/deploying-rails-apps-part-6-writing-capistrano-tasks/), the execute syntax is not written in symbol format.

Lastly, because finding standard, consistent, and reliable Capistrano syntax is such an ordeal, I've run out of options/leads to try to trouble shoot this. Does anyone have any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Derp. I've found my error. The old syntax didn't specify the roles keyword in the task.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like capistrano could have set up a more helpful error message. Here's what worked for me:

for cap2:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Generate static error pages"
  task :generate_static_error_pages do
    run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake app:generate_static_error_pages"
  end
end
```

for cap3:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Generate static error pages"
  task :generate_static_error_pages do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake app:generate_static_error_pages"
    end
  end
end
```

The two changes:

- run becomes execute
- nest the 'execute' line in an 'on roles(:web)' block.